# Troubleshoot script to maintaining/updating Google Calendar with Google Spreadsheet including automatically changing colors

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am trying to write a Google app script to accomplish the following:

- Update a Google calendar based on a couple of columns in a Google
  spreadsheet that signify:
- a. whether the event has a date specified (column "date" != " ")
- b. whether the event has already been posted to the calendar
  (column "In Calendar" = " ").
- Once the event has been added to calendar, I would like to add "Yes" to a column in the spreadsheet (column "In calendar).
- If possible, automatically change color of event based on attributes in a specific column (i.e. if column "State" = NM, then the color of event is blue, if "State" = MT, then the color of event is purple, etc.)

I've looked at various postings throughout the web (mainly http://blog.ouseful.info/2010/03/07/maintaining-a-google-calendar-from-a-goole-spreadsheet-reprise/ and http://blog.ouseful.info/2010/03/04/maintaining-google-calendars-from-a-google-spreadsheet/),

I have hobbled together the following script:

```js
var IN_CAL = "Yes";

function caltest() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();   // Process any rows with data
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("Oil and Gas Test 3")[0];
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var state = row[2] // 3rd column, column with state
    var desc = row[5]; // 6th column, column with lease description
    var date = row[4]; // 5th column, column with date
    var title = state+": "+desc;
    var inCalendar = row[1]; // 2nd column, tells whether in calendar or not
    if ((inCalendar != IN_CAL)&&(date != " ")) { // Prevents adding duplicates to calendar  
      cal.createAllDayEvent(title, new Date(date))
      var v = parseInt(i)+1;
      sheet.getRange(v, 2, 1).setValue(IN_CAL);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Makes sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
    }
    }
  }
```

In case it helps, the columns of my spreadsheet are in the following order:

> Project Number | In Calendar | State | Lease Date | Date | Description.

I reference "**In Calendar**", "**State**", "**Date**", and "**Description**"

in my script.

It seems to mostly work in that it adds the events to the calendar, except that:

1. The script is adding "Yes" to all cells in column "In Calendar"
   regardless of whether or not there is a date in the column "date";
   and
2. I haven't even attempted to adjust the colors.

Does anyone have any tips on how to get the script to read both the "In Calendar" and "Date" columns when deciding whether a event should be created and the "In Calendar" column should be updated to "Yes"? I know that an event probably won't be created without a date, but I don't want the rows without a date to read "Yes" in the "In Calendar" column. I also want the script to read the entire "In Calendar" column that has data, not a predefined number of rows.

Also, any tips on how to automatically change the colors of individual events?

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Add a breakpoint to your code, by clicking a line number.  You'll get a red dot. See line 12.

[image: Break Point]

Then click the icon of a bug.

[image: Click Bug]

You'll see all the variable values being shown in a window at the bottom of the screen.

[image: Debug Break]

Click the 'Step In' icon:

[image: Step In]

If the date in your spreadsheet cell is formatted as a date, the date value should be something like this:

> Thu Mar 12 2015 19:01:08 GMT-0400 (EDT)

If the cell is formatted as a string, then the test needs to be like this:

```
if (date != "") {
```

But, in any case, step through the code, and view the data type and value of the `date` variable.  (And `inCalendar` variable)  Depending on what value is actually being retrieved, will determine what check you need to make with the condition.

I'm guessing that:

```
(date != " ")
```

Is always evaluating to `true`

Comment: Thanks Sandy Good, that makes sense. The date cell in my spreadsheet is formatted as a date. I understand that the if statement is always evaluating to be true because it is looking for a string that will never be there. How do I write the if statement to answer true only when the date cell is empty?